# A question related Lagrange multipliers in $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I would be happy to get some help with the following problem:

let $a=(a_1, a_2,a_4,a_4)\in \Bbb R^4$,

and $M= \{x\in\Bbb R^4: |x|=1, \langle x, a \rangle =0\}, $

and $f(x_1 ,x_2, x_3, x_4) = \sum_{i=1}^4 a_i^2x_i$ .

I need to find the maximum of $f$ on the set $M$.

**My Attempt:**

I defined $g_1(x)=|x|^2-1$ and $g_2(x)=\langle x, a\rangle$.

Clearly $\nabla f(x)=(a_1^2, a_2^2, a_3^2,a_4^2), \\
\nabla g_1(x)=2x, \\
\nabla g_2(x)=a $

Now using lagrange multipliers i took $t, s\in\Bbb R$ that satisfy: $\nabla f(x) = t\cdot g_1(x) + s\cdot g_2(x)$

And by that I reached the following equstions:
$ a_i^2 = 2t\cdot x_i + s\cdot a_i \ \ (\forall i=1,2,3,4)\\
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1 \\
a_1\cdot x_1 + a_2\cdot x_2 + a_3\cdot x_3 + a_4\cdot x_4 = 0$

And that is where I stuck. From this point the algebra becomes complicated. This question is taken from a previous exam, and so I believe that the solution sould not be based on frustrating algebra...

Is my solution correct? (maybe I did some calculation errors on my attempt?) Is there an easier way to look at this problem? (any "tricks" I have missed?)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Assuming your $t$ is nonzero, then $x \propto \alpha=(a_i^2-sa_i)$. 

So for it to work you need $a \cdot \alpha=0$, which yields one value for $s$. 

Then the value for $t$ is given by the fact that $\|\alpha\|=2|t|$. 

If $t$ is zero, then each nonzero $a_i$ is some constant and $a_i^2$ is either zero or one, which makes the optimization easy.

Comment: I will surely try this... thank you for you answer!